Unable to export Bar graph to EXCEL sheet
I am using ant design Bar graph  , I am trying to export Bar graph to excel worksheet.
I tried to convert <Bar/> from UI to Object using html2canvas.
Currently I am getting the converted image URL instead of actual bar graph Image in the excel worksheet cell. Like below...
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0k......
And I can see the actual bar graph image after visiting above URL in browser.
const exportToExcel=()=>{
    const workbook= XLSX2.utils.book_new();
    const chart = document.getElementById('myChart');
        html2canvas(chart).then((canvas) => {
          const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
          const worksheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet([['Chart'], [imgData]]);
          XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, "Chart");
          XLSX.writeFile(workbook, U_${formattedDate}.xlsx, { compression: true });
        });
      };

I want to export Bar graph to excel worksheet

You are almost there, you need to also populate the image, not the base64 encoding of it (I've used xlsx-populate lib in the past, there might be other alternatives):
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
import XLSXPopulate from 'xlsx-populate';

const exportToExcel = () => {
    const chart = document.getElementById('myChart');
    html2canvas(chart).then((canvas) => {
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        // Convert base64 to binary
        const base64Image = imgData.split(",")[1];
        const binaryImage = atob(base64Image);
        const len = binaryImage.length;
        const binaryArray = new Uint8Array(len);
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            binaryArray[i] = binaryImage.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        
        // Use XLSX-populate to add image to worksheet
        XLSXPopulate.fromBlankAsync().then(workbook => {
            const sheet = workbook.sheet(0);
            // Set the cell to display "Chart" as a label for the image
            sheet.cell("A1").value("Chart");

            // Add the image at a specified cell and set dimensions
            sheet.addImage({
                base64: imgData,
                name: "Chart Image",
                anchor: "A2", // The top-left cell for the image
                ext: "png",
                width: 500, // Set width as required
                height: 300, // Set height as required
            });

            // Export the workbook to an Excel file
            workbook.outputAsync().then(blob => {
                const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                const a = document.createElement("a");
                a.href = url;
                a.download = `Chart_${new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)}.xlsx`;
                a.click();
                URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            });
        });
    });
};

